# Switch Focus of cursor between splitted terminals in vs code through shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have seen many answers here to switch between the terminals and panes on vs code in here, but hardly found any addressing the situation for navigating shortcut when the vs code has multiple terminals split in a single screen .

Comment: I think I found it its `Alt +  Left` (left arrow key) and `Alt + Right`(right arrow key) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_key-bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it its Alt + Left (left arrow key) and Alt + Right(right arrow key)